# EventBus communication between two fragments shows No subscribers registered for event class..?

Tags: android, android-fragments, event-bus, greenrobot-eventbus-3.0

First Time I'm trying to implement EventBus to communicate **two fragments** of MyActivity (to change button.setEnabled)
my SDK 21

this is my POJO event

```
public class ButtonEvent {

public final boolean status;
public ButtonEvent(boolean status){

    this.status=status;
}
```

}

this is the fragment that fires the event...

```
Fragment A
...//some code
 @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_a, container, false);
...//more code inside onCreateView
  btnChange.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
//HERE I POST THE EVENT
            EventBus.getDefault().post(new ButtonEvent(true));
}
```

here is the fragmentB which receives (listen) the event...

```
FragmentB extends Fragment{
...//some code
@Override
// in method onCreate I register the subscriber
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if(!EventBus.getDefault().hasSubscriberForEvent(ButtonEvent.class)) {
        EventBus.getDefault().register(this);
    }

}
 @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_b, container, false);
//...some other code
}
//HERE IS MI SUBSCRIBER
@Subscribe
public void onEvent(ButtonEvent event){
    
    btnNuevoMed.setEnabled(event.status);
    btnNuevoMed.setText("hELLOOO");
}
```

this is my output but the app doesn't stop, but doesn't make any change on my fragmentB button:

```
D/EventBus: No subscribers registered for event class ar.com.titaves.consultoriosapp.servicios.ButtonEvent
D/EventBus: No subscribers registered for event class org.greenrobot.eventbus.NoSubscriberEvent
```

my eventbus version:

```
compile 'org.greenrobot:eventbus:3.0.0'
```

there are similar questions but some of them haven't got the right answer and the other are different situations Activity-fragment are not the same implementation than fragment to fragment.

Is my code right? I am missing something? Why it is not working and how can I **solve** the problem? thanks in advance...

Comment: I think u forgot to create subscriber for FragmentA,please have a look.

Comment: @SachinVarma both fragments must create the subscriber not only the fragmentB which is listening? can you show me how and where to code it, please?

Comment: yes u have to create subscriber for Fragment A also

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a sample..

```
          Fragment A
            ...//some code
             @Override
            public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                     Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_a, container, false);
            ...//more code inside onCreateView
              btnChange.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
            //HERE I POST THE EVENT
                        EventBus.getDefault().post(new ButtonEvent(true));
            }
});
}

        @Subscribe
        public void onEvent(ButtonEvent event){

        }

    @Override
      public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        if (!EventBus.getDefault().isRegistered(getActivity())) {
          EventBus.getDefault().register(this);
        }
      }

      @Override
      public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        EventBus.getDefault().unregister(this);
      }
```

Fragment B:

```
    FragmentB extends Fragment{
    ...//some code
    @Override
    // in method onCreate I register the subscriber
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    }
     @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_b, container, false);
    //...some other code
    }
    //HERE IS MI SUBSCRIBER
    @Subscribe
    public void onEvent(ButtonEvent event){

        btnNuevoMed.setEnabled(event.status);
        btnNuevoMed.setText("hELLOOO");
    }
 @Override
      public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        if (!EventBus.getDefault().isRegistered(getActivity())) {
          EventBus.getDefault().register(this);
        }
      }

      @Override
      public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        EventBus.getDefault().unregister(this);
      }
```

Comment: i try your code, the output problem is solved (No subscribers registered for event class..) there are no error, BUT my button doesn't update from enable(false) to true i know this is another problem but you know why my fragmentB doesn't update my button status or refresh the fragment? thanks anyway

Comment: or shuld i add some code in fragmentA Subscriber method? or just leave it empty? because there are no errors but nothig happens and change